# geolocation in webview for Android

Tags: android, geolocation, webview

I developed a web application and I tried to use webview. Everything works fine except the geolocation (which works perfectly in web)

Does anybody have an example of a webview with geolocation?

This is the code for webview:

```
package com.androidpeople.view;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.webkit.WebView;
    
    public class WebViewExample extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.loadUrl("http://myweb.com");
        webView.setWebViewClient(new HelloWebViewClient());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
myWebView.getSettings().setGeolocationDatabasePath(<yourpath>);
myWebView.getSettings().setGeolocationEnabled(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Add these lines in my java code before loading the url and then you will be able to see the geo-coordinates.

```
webView.getSettings().setGeolocationEnabled(true);
webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
     public void onGeolocationPermissionsShowPrompt(String origin, GeolocationPermissions.Callback callback) {
        // callback.invoke(String origin, boolean allow, boolean remember);              
        callback.invoke(origin, true, false);
     }
    });
```

For more information follow the solution in this link -

- [Unable to get GPS coordinates using Javascript on browser in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11280946/unable-to-get-gps-coordinates-using-javascript-on-browser-in-android/11298468#11298468)